# Django: add ForeignKey limit_choices_to associate another or same Model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is my code.

```
std_name = models.ForeignKey(
StudentInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def get_std_class_name(self):
   return int(self.std_name.std_subject_class.std_class_name_N)

def limit_subject_std_choices():
   return {'std_subject_class__std_class_name_N':'get_std_class_name' }

subject_name = models.ForeignKey(StdSubject,on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=limit_subject_std_choices)
```

But shows error. **ValueError at /admin/results/studentinfo/1/change/ invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'get_std_class_name'**

I dont know what is issue with my code. I wanna when any student put her marks any subject while subject will be showed base her class name. 
Just I wanna get student class info from this model instance and pass a value within this function.

```
def limit_subject_std_choices():
       return {'std_subject_class__std_class_name_N':'get_std_class_name'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Django doc of **`limit_choices_to`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to), the value should be a **`dict`** with an expression as `key` and the value as `dict value`
In your case, you are trying to find the values for ***each instance*** in your model, **which is not possible**.

> Then what is possible in your case?

The `std_subject_class__std_class_name_N` expecting a **`PK`** value, (a integer value), so you **should** pass a *valid* integer as

```
subject_name = models.ForeignKey(StdSubject, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 limit_choices_to={'std_subject_class__std_class_name_N': 123})
```

Comment: You are right. But Now I want to math student study class with the subject study class and return query. How can I do that? you can check my another question  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439539/django-tabularinline-admin-put-instance-value-in-formfield-for-foreignkey)